# ¿Cómo acceder a un controlador de Api de aplicación Asp.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Tengo una aplicación Asp.Net Core y en la carpeta Controller agregue un controlador de API  y en este un método UploadFileMethod  ahora

¿Cómo puedo acceder a este?  he probado con varias URLs y me devuelve error 404 Not Found -> no lo encuentra

¿Qué debo hacer para solucionar esto?

```
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ExternalController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]

        public string UploadFileMethod(IFormFile file)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {

               try
                {
                    string path = Path.Combine("Archivos", file.FileName);
                    var stream = System.IO.File.Create(path);
                    file.CopyTo(stream);
                    stream.Dispose();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                  return ex.ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {

               return "null";
            }
            return "Test+";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya leíste sobre peticiones y verbos de APIs ? Hay software específico para realizar estas pruebas, ejemplo postman

Comment: Solo debes quitar la palabra controller de tu URL, quedaría http://{server}:{port}/api/external y especificar que el método utilizado es POST. Reemplaza el dato de server y port y listo

Answer (score 1):

1. Quita del controller el atributo `[Route("api/[controller]")]`
2. Colocar la ruta sobre el metodo   `[Route("api/UploadFileMethod")]`
3. La url queda por ejemplo algo asi: `http://localhost:4200/api/UploadFileMethod`

codigo:

```
namespace ChilePlacer.Controllers
{

    [ApiController]
    public class ExternalController : ControllerBase
    {

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("api/UploadFileMethod")]
        public string UploadFileMethod(IFormFile file)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    var respuesta = new RespuestaModel();

                    if (!file.FileName.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(".JPG") || file.FileName.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(".JPEG") || 
                        file.FileName.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(".BMP") || file.FileName.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(".PNG"))
                    
                        return "El archivo debe ser de tipo: ( .jpg .jpeg  .bmp  .png )"; 
                    
                    string path = Path.Combine("Archivos", file.FileName);
                    var stream = System.IO.File.Create(path);
                    file.CopyTo(stream);
                    stream.Dispose();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return ex.ToString(); ;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "El valor no puede ser nulo";
            }

            return "OK";
        }
    }
}
```